# How does a virus scanner inspect URLs entered in a browser?

Tags: antivirus

I have a virus scanner installed (avast on Windows 8) and it blocked the access to malicious websites in Chromium. There's no proxy activated in Chromium so how is the scanner capable of rejected a connection to some websites? Is there some kind of kernel module that has a low level access?

Comment: Some virus scanners install their browser extension in the system so they can control the browser and block access to malicious websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anti-virus (AV) software usually install their own [NDIS Intermediate Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Windows Filtering Platform Callout Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg158951.aspx) which allows them to tap into the network traffic, modify it, drop it, divert it, and basically do whatever they want.

So when your browser sends a request to a potentially dangerous website, the AV sniffs the HTTP request parameters and compares the URL to a list of blacklisted URLs and when it finds it there it drops request. It's even capable of responding to your browser with a page telling you that the request has been blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You AV product probably uses [DLL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) to intercept the requests to be initiated by your browser:

http://www.file.net/process/aswwebrepie.dll.html

It is possible to achieve similar or higher level of control by [filter drivers](https://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/intrusion/interception-automating-blocking-malicious-traffic-based-ndis-intermediate-driver_33694).